# WooCommerce Mystile theme thumbnails

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

I recently installed Mystile and I m not sure how to resize the thumbnails.

Here:

http://automotiveowner.com/

here:

http://automotiveowner.com/shop/

and the big thumbnail on the single page:

http://automotiveowner.com/product/pathfinder-2013-8pc-pillar-posts/

they all just cut off the front and end of the car.

What do I need to edit to have the thumbnails show the whole car?

```
MYSTILE 1.2.8
FRAMEWORK 5.5.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else comes across this problem, just turn off the hard crop option in WooCommerce Settings -> Catalog -> Image Options